# Como usar variable que devuelva un return

Tags: php, funciones

Soy bastante torpe con las funciones, y más con el uso del `return`.

Tengo este código:

```
    public function addAuthor($autor, $nacimiento, $descripcion) {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO autores (Autor, Nacimiento, Descripcion) VALUES (:autor, :nacimiento, :descripcion)");
        $sql->execute(array(':autor'=>$autor, ':nacimiento'=>$nacimiento, ':descripcion'=>$descripcion));

        $lastID = $this->db->lastInsertId('IDAutor');

        return $lastID;
    }
```

Necesito usar el `$lastID` para poder renombrar la foto con el id y después subirla.

esté es el código del controlador:

```
$c->addAuthor($name, $nacimiento, $description);
```

¿Cómo haría para coger el resultado del `$lastID`? ¿Habría que llamar a la función de otra manera? Estoy muy perdido con el tema del `return`. He intentado leer en la guía de `PHP` sobre el `return` pero sigo sin ver la forma.

Comment: Sí su función está correcta y desea asignar el valor que retorna su función podría ser `$id = $c->addAuthor($name, $nacimiento, $description);` el `$lastId`  estará en la variable `$id`

Comment: @Dev.Joel funciona perfectamente así, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que no quede abierta la pregunta, Si su función está correctamente escrita y devuelve los valores esperados solo tendría que asignar el valor a una variable  `X` para utilizar ese valor en donde lo requiera.

```
/* En la variable $id tendrá el valor devuelto por la función */
$id = $c->addAuthor($name, $nacimiento, $description);
```

Comment: Tengo el cooldown de verificar la respuesta, ahora la verifico cuando acabe